# Animation to Transition css property

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

code in the link below is suppose to make an animation which, after 5 seconds (that's just a simulation - in a real world scenario the trigger would be when content loads), should end the animation and proceed with the transition property (dots should change its size to 0 and get to the initial position).

[JsFiddle code](https://jsfiddle.net/m3wj5zsw/44/)

```
#loading-icon {
    display: flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#shell.done .dot {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    top: 0;
    animation: none;
    transition: 2s all;
}

.dot {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes bounce {
    0% {
        top: 0%;
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        animation-timing-function: eas-out;
  }
  25% {
    top: -50%;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
    50% {
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
    }
  75% {
        top: 50%;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
    100% {
        width: 12px;
        height: 12px;
        top: 0%;
  }
}

.dot:nth-child(1) {
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}

.dot:nth-child(2) {
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

.dot:nth-child(3) {
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
```

Any idea how to accomplish such behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: no it's not like you think ... you remove the animation so you get back immediatly to initial state ... you cannot have a transition for an animation state to a normal state

Comment: @TemaniAfif Okay, but there has to be way to achieve such behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the use of iteration and the `animationend` event:

```js
var x=document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
  x[i].addEventListener("animationend", function(e){
     setTimeout(function(a = e.target) {
        a.classList.add('done');
     },500);
  })
}
```

```css
#loading-icon {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}



.dot {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  transition:0.5s;
}

.done {
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    top: 0%;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    animation-timing-function: eas-out;
  }
  25% {
    top: -50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }
  50% {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
  75% {
    top: 50%;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  100% {
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    top: 0%;
  }
}

.dot:nth-child(1) {
  animation: bounce 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

.dot:nth-child(2) {
  animation: bounce 2s;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}

.dot:nth-child(3) {
  animation: bounce 2s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-iteration-count: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="shell">
  <div id="loading-icon">
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
    <div class="dot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it just jumped to the top: 0 and then sized down and thats not smooth at all.

Comment: @TomasB did you check the last update ? which part is not smooth ?